# Excel Formula Suddenly Breaks Down

Tags: excel

I have a formula using MATCH, which uses one piece of data that comes from the result of the same formula in the previous row.

However one point it suddenly stops working. see the #N/A below in image 1, and the actual formulas in image 2.

It appears that from breaking down the formula into its components, that the MATCH function can't find a match for "5.004", despite it clearly being in the data set on the left.

[image]

[image]

Comment: My guess is that C4 has more decimal places than what is being showed.  Anything between 5.0035 and 5.00449 would show up as 5.004 if that is what the display is set, but Excel uses the actual value and not the displayed value.

Comment: I have entered exactly 5.004 into C4, I checked that.

Comment: check for String vs Numbers(they don't match each other). Take off any alignment--> string naturally sit to the left, numbers align to the right in the cell.

Comment: I entered all the data the same, the formulas work for a while, then stop working.  It looks from further research like the order of the data set is important.  that's the reason i used index, to avoid the order issues of vlookup

Comment: Sorting was red herring.  F4 is taking an entered number (5.001) and adding the result of a formula, which row 4 can use (perhaps when adding an entered number and formula, the "type" adopts the entered number format?)  The row where it breaks is a formula that's adding the results of two other formulas.

Now, ALL the cells are formatted as "0.000" so they ARE all the same, however, if I type in 5.004 in F5, the other formulas work.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `MATCH` only works with sorted data.  Here is the way I came up to solve your issue by using `INDEX` and `SUMPRODUCT`.

Under *cell G3*, you can enter this formula and copy down:

`=INDEX($B$3:$B$6,SUMPRODUCT(--($C$3:$C$6=F3)*ROW(($C$3:$C$6)))-2,1)`

- Please note `SUMPRODUCT` will use a lot of CPU power, so make a smaller range is a better way to go.
- Since `SUMPRODUCT` doesn't return string, therefore, I use the `ROW` function to return the row number and subtract two due to two header rows.

Under *cell H3*, here is the formula for you to use and remember to copy down:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--($C$3:$C$6=F3),$D$3:$D$6)`

Hope this helps.